# Probleme xsl:use-attribute-sets display just the last attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to generate an xml file to generate a pdf file by FOP. So i have a probleme with the element xsl:use-attribute-sets. when a try to generate a xml file formated by a xsl file using xsltproc  in the xml file result i have juste the last attribute seted on my xsl:attribute-set.

I use the xsltproc.

My xsl:attribute-set :

```
  <xsl:attribute-set name="my.style">
        <xsl:attribute name="table-layout">fixed</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="inline-progression-dimension">auto</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="width">80%</xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">1cm</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
```

I call this attribute set on:

```
<fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="my.style">
...
```

The result :

```
<fo:table margin-top="1cm">
...
```

Comment: You'll need to present a [mcve].  In my testing, xsltproc correctly adds all the attributes of your attribute set when it instantiates a template containing a literal result element that uses that set.